# Get Command number in databricks

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-notebook

How can i get the current command number dynamically from a cell in Azure databricks notebook? Is there any dbutils command to retrieve it?

For below cell, it should return 1.

[image: Databricks command example]

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct built-in function in dbutils or Spark to retrieve the current command number dynamically from a cell in an Azure Databricks notebook.

I have tried the following approach:

```
spark._jsparkSession.sparkContext().getLocalProperty("spark.databricks.notebook.id")
result = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM default.my_table")
print(f"Current command number: {command_number}")
```

[image]

**Result:**

```
Current command number: 2585995787002146
```

`spark._jsparkSession.sparkContext().getLocalProperty("spark.databricks.notebook.id")`:
The command above retrieves the number of the current cell in the Databricks notebook.

- It uses the **SparkSession (spark)** to access the underlying Java
  SparkSession, then gets the local property
  "`spark.databricks.notebook.id`" which holds the command number.
- The code uses the Spark context `(spark._jsparkSession.sparkContext())`
  to access a property that represents the current command number associated with the notebook.
- This property, `spark.databricks.notebook.id`, uniquely identifies each command execution within the notebook. The `getLocalProperty` method is then used to retrieve the value of this property, which corresponds to the command number.